If $a\le b\le c$ are the sides of a triangle of area $A$, circumradius $R$ and inradius $r$, is it true that $P(c+b-a>R+r+\sqrt{A})= \frac{3}{4}$?
If $a \le b \le c$ be the length of the sides of a triangle of area $A$ whose vertices are uniformly random on a circle of radius $R$, and let its inradius be $r$. The largest deficit between the sum of two sides and the third side is $c+b-a$. We can compare this to the quantity $R + r + \sqrt{A}$ since both are in the units of length. What is the probability that the former is greater than the latter? Numerical evidences with more than $2 \times 10^9$ gives a probability of $0.749938$ which is suspiciously close to $3/4$.
Question: Is it true that
$$
P(c+b-a > R + r + \sqrt{A}) = \frac{3}{4} ?
$$
If true, this will be another example of a geometric probabilities having a rational value. In that case, if there an intuitive explanation why it is $3/4$?

After 10 billion tests, I found probability to be 75.00138749%. I have also changed random number generators on every 30 million tests to avoid bias that is often found in software randomizers. If someone wants to push things further I will gladly share my Java code (heavily parallelized, it uses every single core in your CPU).
